# how to check first element of array and some jsx

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I need to check my array and the first element jxs should be different from other elements jsx.

Array:

```
[
  {
    title: 'sth'
  },
  {
    title: 'sth'
  },
  {
    title: 'sth'
  }
]
```

first element:

```
<>
  <img src="" />  // its static and has no flag in array
  <div>{item.title}</div>
</>
```

second element:

```
<>
  <div>{item.title}</div>
</>
```

data is dynamic and I just need to add image to the first element in jsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would question whether the image needs to be part of the first element (especially since you're using fragments) -- you might be able to do this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ values }) => (
  <img src="" />
  {values.map((item) => (
    <div>{item.title}</div>
  )}
)
```

If that won't work for you, you can use the `index` parameter in the function you pass to `map`...

```
const MyComponent = ({ values }) => (
  {values.map((item, index) => (
    {index === 0 && <img src="" />}
    <div>{item.title}</div>
  )}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your first item in the array is the only one with a 'src' for an image, you can use [Condition Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) when mapping over the array in your return.

```
const items = [{ title: 'sth', src: 'https://image.png' }, { title: 'sth' }, { title: 'sth' }]

return (
  <>
    {items.map(item => (
      <>
        {item.src && <img src={item.src} />}
        <div>{item.title}</div>
      </>
    ))}
  </>
)
```

This syntax is basically a short hand `if` statement. It will check the item to see if the src property exists or is `undefined`, which is falsey and the statement becomes:

```
if(item.src == true) {
   return <img src={item.src}/>
} else {
   return null
}
```

`null` is a valid return for JSX.

I recommend to study the Reacts page on Conditional Rendering.

Comment: there is no src key in the object.